# Copying jQuery offset from one element to another puts them in different places

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is given 2 divs, one with tagged content, generate new content in the other div that is vertically aligned with the first. A minimal example of what I've got so far is below in the snippet.

I've tried doing adjustments like subtracting `$('sidebar').offset().top` and/or the height of the header from the new element's top-side offset (thinking that maybe the new element was offsetting from the top of the sidebar instead of the document for some reason), but that still doesn't put it in the right place.

I think the hurdle here is figuring out why `tag_offset.top` and `test_tip.offset().top` aren't equal at the end, even though that's explicitly being assigned when `test_tip` is instantiated.

```js
var tag_offset = $('.jt-tooltip-tag').offset();
tag_offset['left'] = 0;
var tag_text = $('.jt-tooltip-text').text();

var test_tip = $('<div class="jt-sidebar-tip">').text(tag_text).offset(tag_offset).appendTo('#jt-tooltip-sidebar');
```

```css
.middlebar {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 500px;
  width: 49%;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.jt-tooltip-tag {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #14c9c9;
}

.jt-tooltip-text {
  display: none;
}

.jt-sidebar-tip {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <h1 class="header">
    Omigosh a header!
  </h1>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="middlebar">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nec tortor justo. Donec magna neque, interdum eu diam ut, efficitur pharetra ligula. Aenean libero justo, feugiat a est a, hendrerit cursus justo. Donec vehicula ligula ut diam bibendum, vel
      convallis purus blandit. Nulla <span class="jt-tooltip"><span class="jt-tooltip-tag">facilisi.</span><span class="jt-tooltip-text">This should be vertically-aligned with facilisi.</span></span> Donec pretium, leo at commodo dignissim, eros
      ligula vulputate sem, quis iaculis turpis est ac erat. Ut ultrices mauris efficitur tellus gravida convallis vitae ac magna. Nullam vel enim ut eros tempor dictum et quis risus. Aliquam finibus sed justo eu porttitor.
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar" id="jt-tooltip-sidebar">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to position an element relative to the document, you need to set its CSS to `position: absolute;`. But then you also need to set its `left` offset to a position that puts it into its container. I've done this by copying `$("#jt-tooltip-sidebar").offset().left`.

```js
var tag_offset = $('.jt-tooltip-tag').offset();
tag_offset.left = $("#jt-tooltip-sidebar").offset().left;
var tag_text = $('.jt-tooltip-text').text();

var test_tip = $('<div class="jt-sidebar-tip">').text(tag_text).offset(tag_offset).appendTo('#jt-tooltip-sidebar');
```

```css
.middlebar {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 500px;
  width: 49%;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.jt-tooltip-tag {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #14c9c9;
}

.jt-tooltip-text {
  display: none;
}

.jt-sidebar-tip {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <h1 class="header">
    Omigosh a header!
  </h1>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="middlebar">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nec tortor justo. Donec magna neque, interdum eu diam ut, efficitur pharetra ligula. Aenean libero justo, feugiat a est a, hendrerit cursus justo. Donec vehicula ligula ut diam bibendum, vel
      convallis purus blandit. Nulla <span class="jt-tooltip"><span class="jt-tooltip-tag">facilisi.</span><span class="jt-tooltip-text">This should be vertically-aligned with facilisi.</span></span> Donec pretium, leo at commodo dignissim, eros
      ligula vulputate sem, quis iaculis turpis est ac erat. Ut ultrices mauris efficitur tellus gravida convallis vitae ac magna. Nullam vel enim ut eros tempor dictum et quis risus. Aliquam finibus sed justo eu porttitor.
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar" id="jt-tooltip-sidebar">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I just came to the same realization and it does get me where I want to be. For further edification, would you happen to know why setting it to relative messes up the top offset the way it does? It seems like if it was going to mess it up, it would just be adding the offset from the parent (the sidebar), or something like that, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: That's exactly what it's doing. When I inspect your version, it says that the top is 187.5px, and that's its position from the top of the sidebar element.

Comment: Oh I see where I was grabbing the offset from the wrong spot to check that. Thank you very much!